# Software to calculate electron binding energy of molecules?

Tags: resource-recommendations, software, molecules, quantum-chemistry, orbitals

I need to calculate the binding energies for the various electrons in a few different molecules (to determine an appropriate wavelength to selectively ionize them). Are there any software packages to do this or am going to have to read a text book and do it by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chemist's terms you are looking for the ionization energy of the molecule. I imagine most standard quantum chemistry programs should be able to calculate this. If you have access, try out Gaussian. Otherwise Orca is a great quantum chemistry binary that is freely available. Both resources have great manuals.